# FFX HD Remaster on Vita: VICTORIOUS password not working

Tags: ps-vita, final-fantasy-10

I am playing on my PS Vita FFX HD Remaster (Italian language).
I got the airship and using the Password system I managed to unlock on the first try the Murasame area through the use of "MURASAME" password.
For the God Hand I had issues, guides stated the password was GODHAND but what worked was GOD HAND.
Now I can't seem to find a suitable replacement for VICTORIOUS, since it's not working. Any idea?

Comment: I don't have the answer or the ability to check it for a while, but those passwords came from [deciphering clues](http://chaos2.org/ff/ff10/passwords.shtml). If the password doesn't work, could you maybe try checking if the clues have changed? The VICTORIOUS password came from the blue stones at Kilika and Bikanel (alternate letters from each stone) so I would start by checking those stones.

Comment: The original passwords worked fine for me in the PS3 version. Are you sure you are spelling it correctly etc?

Comment: Of course. I tried it several times. GODHAND wouldn't work, but GOD HAND did. As for the other one...no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried "VICTORIAS" instead? According to [this post](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/directmessage.php?m=14670707), some versions of the game have different passwords/spellings:

> Some versions (like Italian/spanish) have different passwords than the English versions. For example, in the Italian version, the password for Rikku's weapon is VICTORIAS.

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm (though VICTORIAS isn't an italian word!).